# Swift - Push to ViewController from UIButton in CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to make my button, when tapped, to push to a new View Controller. I've tried many different ways but it won't trigger the function that I have it linked to. I also checked the 3D stack view of my layers and the button is on top and clickable, even when I check the background color, it's not being covered by anything else.

Does anyone have any ideas to what I am doing wrong?

For now I am trying to make the button print out the sentence in the console, however whenever I press it, the string doesn't pop up, so I haven't bothered to connect it to the view controller yet.

Also, I am coding this app without storyboards.

Here is my code below.

It is under the MainPageCell class declared as a UICollectionViewCell

```
private let playButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainPageCell.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc func buttonTapped() {
    print("I PRESSED THE BUTTON")
}
```

Comment: The duplicate is about doing this in a table view but doing it in a collection view is identical once you tweak the specific APIs being used.

Comment: thank you, but besides the segue part, my first question is why the button isn't even working properly when pressed, it won't print out the print statement

Comment: Oops. Reopened.

Comment: Could you add more details? Are you trying to add a button to inside collection view cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainPageCell.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

You cannot assign `self` as the action target in a property declaration initializer, because the instance designated by `self` does not exist yet. There is no error or warning (I regard that as a bug), but the action method is never called.

Move that assignment elsewhere and rewrite it, like this:

```
self.playButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainPageCell.buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked! Just to clarify, I shouldn't have to put the action target in the playButton property because the whole button hasn't been initialized yet? Rather, say I put it in the viewDidLoad, or in this case I put the assignment in a override init.... block, this way, when the button is loaded, it the target will initialize because there is actually a button to work with. I think i understand what I did wrong here!

Comment: OMG, I spent at least an hour debugging this problem. TY!

Comment: @livingtech Yeah, it's frustrating isn't it? Like I say, I regard this as a bug. At least the compiler should warn you, "Hey, this doesn't do what you think it does!"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try defining your button action under the UIView Class, I've had a problem like that before, only worked when i linked it to the View Class, Good luck